# How to create a new Gson from the existing Gson?

Tags: gson

I have a `Gson` instance created by 3rd party code. I need to add some changes to it before it gets used by the 3rd party code. I do have entrypoints to get/set `Gson` instance.

How can I get a `GsonBuilder` from the existing Gson instance? I need to copy the existing configuration and add some more.

GsonBuilder, GsonFireBuilder... they don't have anything like that.

Comment: `Gson.newBuilder()`. Will give you a builder based on the current `Gson` config.

Comment: Thanx! I totally missed that method. Could you please answer so I can mark the question as answered??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Gson.newBuilder()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.10.1/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#newBuilder()). This will give you a `GsonBuilder` based of the current configured `Gson` instance.